# Symfony 3.3 FORM, validate a JSON (in an API) through $form->submit($data)

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation

I'm testing some "**API** developing" methods in **Symfony 3.3**

I just run through a tutorial, which told me that I could **use Symfony Forms to**:

1. Automatically **validate JSON**;
2. Automatically **fill the new entity** with the JSON data.

So I created a method "POST", which I use to create a resource, say USER.

2. I POST to that method with the following rawbody:
   {"name": "foo", "surname": "bar", "userType": 1}
3. The tutorial said I could do those two "automatic things" with form, by writing the following lines of code:

   ```
   $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

   $user = new User();

   $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user );

   $form->submit($data);

   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

   $em->persist($user);

   $em->flush();
   ```

The form class "UserType" has the following lines of code:

```
namespace FooBundle\Form;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('surname', TextType::class)
            ->add('userType', ChoiceType::class, array(
                    'choices' => array(
                        1 => 'one',
                        2 => 'two',
                        3 => 'three',
                        4 => 'four',
                        5 => 'five',
                        6 => 'six',
                    )
                )
            )
        ;
    }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                "data_class" => "FooBundle\Entity\User"
            )
        );

    }

}
```

When I post to that endpoint, however, I have the following error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user(name, surname,
>   user_type) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params ["foo", "bar", null]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'user_type' cannot be null

Why does the form **does not automatically fill in the "user type" field**?

Did I do something wrong in the **"ChoiceType" field** of the form?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options of your `ChoiceType` field are inverted. Your `choices` option array should be the over way around as explained [in the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices):

> The `choices` option is an array, where the array key is the item's label and the array value is the item's value

As it is, when your form handles the request data, it stumbles upon an integer which does not belong to the expected values for the `userType`. This case is handled by simply ignoring the given value which is why you end up with a `null` value.

Long story short, you have to write your `choices` array like this in your case:

```
'choices' => ['one' => 1, 'two' => 2, ...]
```